# Forzar una descarga PDF en Safari

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, safari

Tengo esta directiva en el HTACCESS que funciona bien en los demás navegadores, pero en Safari, elementos Apple, no me funciona. No se realiza la descarga.

```
#Safari
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.pdf$" requested_pdf=pdf
Header add Content-Disposition "attachment" env=requested_pdf
#Any
 <Files *.pdf>
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    Header add Content-Disposition "attachment"
</Files>
```

Saben que podría ser?

Ese Primero que dice Safari lo agregue basado en una solución que vi. Pero nada. No me funciona.

Cabe destacar que los archivos tienen "-" guiones. Y estoy trabajando en Wordpress.

Comment: Para probar he puesto **únicamente** esto en el `.htaccess` y me funciona perfectamente: **`<Files *.pdf*>
        ForceType application/octet-stream
        Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    </Files>`**  si intento abrir un PDF por URL me lo descarga. Estoy usando Safari y Wordpress. Puse la directiva al principio del `.htaccess` Probé también poniendo todo lo que tienes y funciona igualmente. Puede entonces que sea el mismo `.htaccess` que sobreescribe la directiva más adelante, o alguna restricción de tu hosting.

Comment: Lo extraño es que si es una restricción del Hosting, debería hacerlo con todos no?, no únicamente con Safari.

Probare a colocar este, al inicio como dices. Los unicos plugins que pudiesen reescribir el .htaccess serian WP SUPER CACHE y Autoptimizer. Será desactivarlos y volver a probar.

Gracias, estaré probando.

Comment: Puedes probar a limpiar el caché y cosas de ese tipo. Como te digo, usando Safari y Wordpress probé la directiva tal y como la indico en mi anterior comentario y me funciona. Y probé también el código justo como lo tienes en la pregunta y también funciona. Por tanto, si a ti no te funciona no es la directiva, debe ser por otra causa.